# what is the best way to code an online multiplayer game?

Tags: server, socket

so i want to create a simple game that runs over a network but I am having trouble deciding what needs to be done in terms of what the server needs to do and what the clients need to do. I understand I should use UDP sockets but I am unsure how to implement it within a game and have all the clients be in sync. Should the server side have like a master copy of the game where i basically runs the game and accepts moves, plays them in itself, and then sends the current state of the object to the other clients?

Comment: Search more and try stuff. You won't learn anything if we code it for you. _"Should the server side have like a master copy of the game where i basically runs the game and accepts moves, plays them in itself, and then sends the current state of the object to the other clients?"_ Asking the question is answering it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most of cases the relationship is simple:

> Client -> Input to server
>   Server -> Calculate logic and physics, send object position and property data back to client
>   Client -> Render the scene using received data

I guess that this is what you where asking for!;)

Comment: oh ok thanks!   so if this was a simple game of pong for example, the client would send the input of when you click a key to the server and the server would return the new coordinates of the paddle and it would check if the ball collides and return the new state of the ball?

Comment: If client clicks a key, it sends the input to server. Than server checks the key and, if it was, for example, up arrow key, than it moves player's object upwards. However, server does calculations all the time, even if there's no input. It needs to calculate the ball's position and send it to the client. And than client renders the ball in it's new position.

Comment: You should probably also try to predict where things are moving or the screen will basically freeze on the client.

Comment: If you have 30 ms or smaller ping(my internet connection with a normal server is around 20 ms ping) than you don't need to. Elseway you need to do some linear math using current linear velocity and applying it duirng connectionless frames. Hm... This can lead to some incompletnesses. But relationship delays can cause some input problems. Uh... Propably we need good internet connection...

Comment: Also consider that if any processing overhead is taken on by the host, you potentially reduce the power required on the client side; Allowing users with lower-specced models to access your game.

Comment: @Adrians Netlis oh ok. so for pong the ball around be completely handled by the server and it would check for collisions and update the clients right? sorry this is my first time trying a multiplayer game and I've been struggling to find a good approach to this

Comment: So the server would do all the physics calculations. And than just send raw transform data(position, orientation and scale) of objects to client. And than client only needs to render specific objects in specific positions. For static objects you don't need to calculate their positions and transforms on server, you can just handle them in client and make server ignore them(this applies, for example, for the background elements or terrains, or buildings(the non-interactable parts of them) - anything that doesn't move or rotate, or scale).

Comment: @AdriansNetlis ok so for pong the client does absolutely nothing for the ball except displays it on the screen?  LIke it is the server that does everything for the ball and the clients just display it?

Comment: The client gives input. Whenever client press button, a boolean of `true` for the action of specific button is sent to server(if the button isn't down, a boolean of `false` is sent). The server than analyzes the input. For example, if input was for the player's object to move up, than server adds velocity to the object in it's physics equations that causes it to move up(or for non physics version just increments it's position).

Comment: @AdriansNetlis ok I understand the player part of the game but im having trouble understanding how the ball in a game of pong should be handled.  Should the ball basically be run on the server side and update clients on the ball's velocity and such periodically and when it changes? because if it is like this then doesn't that mean the server needs a replica of the game? or should each client handle the ball and send data of the ball to the server to send to the other clients? but wouldn't this cause misalignments in each of the client's versions of the game?

Comment: The ball's logic(velocity, collisions, direction changes and also - position) should be calculated on server. And than it only sends pure data of position and rotation to the player. And player only calculates graphics.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis ok so i started trying to implement everything you've told me and I am having trouble understanding how having the client predict the ball's position helps.  Because if it predicts the ball's position and then it recieves a new packet that gives the ball's position slightly different, won't the animation seem very choppy?

Comment: The prediction won't work, unless you have a physics engine. But you don't need to predict if you have steady ping frequency(e.g. 30 pings/s). Than it's very enaugh physics calculations. You can make 1 frame latency and than interpolate between current frame and previous frame. This would add a minimal bias to game, but would smooth the framerate.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis what do you mean by 1 frame latency?

Comment: You store the frame data of current frame into prev frame variable. Than in next frame assume that prev frame is the current frame. Than you can interpolate between previous frame and current frame when no ping is made.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis ok i hope this is the last thing im going to ask you but you've been a lot of help though, should the client request each frame to be sent to it like after it is done rendering the old frame? or should the server just constantly send out frames?  If the server is constantly sending out frames wouldn't that create a fixed frame rate which is usually not desirable?  But then if the client is requesting each frame couldn't that lower the frame rate for players?

Comment: Fixed frame-rate oftenly is dersirable anyways(V-Sync). Well, I don't know this deep. I told that working one frame before would improve frame-rate. Client shouldn't send anything to server, except logic inputs(keyboard, mouse) if they are needed.